# Firebase update query getting stalled when working with date

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a block of code that updates document data

```
const { serverTimestamp } = firebase.firestore.FieldValue;

// The function firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(data.dob) seems to produce this behaviour
const fsData = {
    ...
    dob: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(data.dob),
    doj: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(data.doj),
    ...
}

try {
    console.log(`fsData`, fsData)
    await db.collection(FIRESTORE_COLLECTIONS.CLIENT_COLLECTION).doc(clientId).update({
        ...fsData,
        updatedAt: serverTimestamp(),
    });
    console.log(`fsData`, fsData)

    return true
} catch (e) {
    console.log(`e`, e)
}
```

After the call to this function, It executes up until first `console.log(`fsData`, fsData)`

Then nothing happens, There is no response or error messages coming up. Then after a few minutes...

After experimenting, It was found that `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(data.dob)` is causing this. Because, whenever i remove those two data, it was working.

The data that's being passed to this function Date type, This works well with creating documents but has issues when updating.

and here's the object right before passing to update

```
fsData 
Object { doj: {…}, dob: {…}, firstName: "Amaya", lastName: "Gilbert", address: "Dolor quaerat quos l", cycle: "24", phone: "+123123123123" }
​
address: "Dolor quaerat quos l"
​
cycle: "24"
​
dob: Object { seconds: 1626449262, nanoseconds: 0 }
​
doj: Object { seconds: 1626535662, nanoseconds: 0 }
​
firstName: "Amaya"
​​
lastName: "Gilbert"
​
phone: "+123123132123"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
clientContext.tsx:128:20
```

`@firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.7.0): Connection WebChannel transport errored:`  appears in console as warning.

Other functions, create and delete works well.

Comment: Is your function `async` in which you have this update operation? Also try 


`firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true });` after initializing it.

Comment: Yeah, I've found its with one particular function I'll update the question